# My Pytorch CNN computes but does not show training results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am writing a CNN to classify some images. when I run the training part of my code, the only output I receive is the print "Training finished". This tells me that my code was iterated through but did not successfully compute - I have no errors and have really tried to identify the error.

The fc1's (First connected layer) input size is supposed to be the flattened previous layer.

## Data

```
train_split = 0.70 # Defines the ratio of train/valid/test data.
valid_split = 0.10

train_size = int(len(data_df)*train_split)
valid_size = int(len(data_df)*valid_split)

ins_dataset_train = ImageNet10(
   df=data_df[:train_size],
   transform=data_transform,
)

ins_dataset_valid = ImageNet10(
   df=data_df[train_size:(train_size + 
   valid_size)].reset_index(drop=True),
   transform=data_transform,
)

ins_dataset_test = ImageNet10(
   df=data_df[(train_size + valid_size):].reset_index(drop=True),
   transform=data_transform,
)
```

## Data Loaders

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
   ins_dataset_train,
   batch_size=16,
   shuffle=True,
   num_workers=2
)
valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
   ins_dataset_valid,
   batch_size=16,
   shuffle=True,
   num_workers=2
)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
   ins_dataset_test,
   batch_size=24, # Forward pass only so batch size can be larger
   shuffle=False,
   num_workers=2
)
```

## Convolutional neural network

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
    super(ConvNet, self).__init__()


    # Add network layers here
    # Layer 1
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,16, (3,3))
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)


        # Layer 2
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16,24, (4,4))
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)

        # Layer 3
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(24,32, (4,4))
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)

        # Layer 4 - Fully connected
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 8 * 8, 512)


    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
    self.final = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

def forward(self, x):
   out = x.reshape(x.size(0), -1) # TODO what does this do? Why do we need it?
   out = self.fc1(out)
   return out
```

## Training Model

```
def train_model_epochs(num_epochs):
  for epoch in range(10):

    running_loss = 0.0

    for i, data in enumerate(test_loader, 0):
      images, labels = data
      print("Batch", i, "size:", len(images))

      optimizer.zero_grad()

      outputs = net(images)

      loss = loss_function(outputs, labels)

      loss.backward()

      optimizer.step()

      running_loss =+ loss.item()
      if i%1000 == 999:
         print('Epoch / Batch [%d / %d] - Loss: %.3f' %
         (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 1000))
         running_loss = 0.0    

  print("Training finished")
```

Comment: If you just get "Training finished" it suggests your `test_loader` is empty

Comment: @AndréPacheco Hi, i have uploaded the data loader section, can you spot any issues with this from what I have posted. Sorry for incorrect formatting.

Comment: Before starting your training do: `print(len(test_loader))` to check how many samples you have.

Comment: @AndréPacheco It prints 75

Comment: don't you get this `print("Batch", i, "size:", len(images))`?

Comment: @AndréPacheco I do not understand your question sorry

Comment: Even with 75 samples inside the dataloader, when you run your code you don't see this print?

Comment: @AndréPacheco Oh, I do not get that print. I only get the "Training finished" print at the end of the training